# Drosophila biarmipes gene annotation, transposable element?

Tags: bioinformatics, drosophila, gene-annotation, horizontal-gene-transfer

When doing an annotation of a contig31 of *Drosophila biarmipes* genome, the gene predictions(in orange, red, green, tan, blue, brown, and gray) picked up numerous possible genes in the area circled in blue below:

[image: GEP genome browser on *D.biarmipes*, dot chromosome, contig 31]

So according to the GEP(genomic education partnership) guide I was reading, I was to then BLASTP the amino acid sequence from these predicted genes to a non-redundant protein database. Using NCBI BLAST I did just that, and observed alot of results of significance (E value < 1 X 10^-5).

Many of the BLASTP results were somthing like:

[image: First BLASTP result, possible TE?]

Reading up on gag proteins I found they were related to transposable element activity, specifically reverse transcriptase activity. So then should I conclude that these regoins are showing a gene because they are a Transposable element, or the remenats of one?

I also found:

[image]

And reading on *Wolbachia* I found that there is Horizontal gene transfer with its genome and *Drosophila* in general, according to wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolbachia#Horizontal_gene_transfer_and_genomics

**So then, can I conclude the area circled in blue is a result of Transposable element, and not an actual gene belonging to *D. biarmipes*?**

Comment: Do a nucleotide BLAST first. This seems to be just a partial match. You cannot conclude that this is a transposable element. Also see if RNAseq data is available.

Comment: @WYSIWYG        THe RNA seq data is in the first picture, under the blue circle, there are black peaks that correlate with RNA seq data, the first is labeled "RNA-Seq alignment summary for mixed embryos". As for the nucleotide BLAST, i did a tBLASTn, since I only had an amino acid file to work with. The results were still a same link to the pol gag protein. The title of the highest significance match was: "Drosophila ananassae retrotransposon putative gag-pol protein gene" .